# Mapbox geoJSON formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mapbox, geojson

I am trying to make an interactive map using MapBox.

The basic idea is that people will hover over certain regions and they will light up and an event will trigger showing some content.

I got the map set up using Mapbox and then went ahead and got some data for the points by first

Going here to create a shapefile - http://www.gadm.org/country

And then going here to convert that file into a json file - http://www.mapshaper.org/

I then load the data into the map via mapbox and here is my result! (code below) - http://dev.touch-akl.com/nzmap/

As you can see thanks to the data I have downloaded it is almost a perfect trace of the country the only problem is that all the regions seem to be ONE object when hovering.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/nzmap/js/nzmap.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function load(data) {

                // set up the regions based on the JSON data and then call the styles and the hovers
                var regions = L.geoJson(data, {
                    style: getStyle,
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                }).addTo(map);

                // selects used to style the regionsLayer
                function getStyle(feature) {
                    return {
                        weight: 2,
                        opacity: 0.1,
                        color: 'black',
                        fillOpacity: 0.7,
                        fillColor: 'red'
                    };
                }

                // combine the mouse in and mouse out?
                function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                    layer.on({
                        mousemove: mousemove,
                        mouseout: mouseout
                    });
                }

                // mouse over change the layer styles
                function mousemove(e) {
                    var layer = e.target;

                    // highlight feature
                    layer.setStyle({
                        weight: 3,
                        opacity: 0.3,
                        fillOpacity: 0.9
                    });

                    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
                        layer.bringToFront();
                    }
                }

                //mouse out reset the style
                function mouseout(e) {
                    regions.resetStyle(e.target);
                }

            }
        });
```

Here is a link to the json file if that helps understand what is going on - http://dev.touch-akl.com/nzmap//js/nzmap.json

It looks like some of the polygons are 'multipolygons' and some are seperate. I managed to create a new version of the map using just one region and it looks like this - http://dev.touch-akl.com/nzmap2/

My function for doing this is much the same except I have split the region off and use a json file that only has the coordinates for that region.

This is the JSON file for that example - http://dev.touch-akl.com/nzmap2/js/waikato.json

**So where I am stuck is...** Is there a way to format the original json file in a way that will keep each region as it's own separate object for hovers? And if so how can I go about changing the way I am setting up the map get the desired result?

It looks like I could make a seperate json file for each region like I am doing with the second example but that just does not seem like the right way to do this, been stuck for days so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because what you are using isn't proper GeoJSON, at least not the GeoJSON L.GeoJSON expects. What you need is a GeoJSON FeatureCollection. A collection would look something like this:

```
[{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-104.05, 48.99],
            [-97.22,  48.98],
            [-96.58,  45.94],
            [-104.03, 45.94],
            [-104.05, 48.99]
        ]]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "bar": "foo"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-109.05, 41.00],
            [-102.06, 40.99],
            [-102.03, 36.99],
            [-109.04, 36.99],
            [-109.05, 41.00]
        ]]
    }
}]
```

As you can see, a FeatureCollection contains individual features which can be or type Point, MultiPoint, LineString, MultiLineString, Polygon or MultiPolygon. If you use a FeatureCollection L.GeoJSON will work as you would expect. Take a look at the reference for [FeatureCollection](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-collection-objects) and [L.GeoJSON](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson). A tutorial/example on using them both can be found [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html).

Comment: Thanks man this post and the links you send helped heaps and I managed to get the map working as planned!

Comment: No problem, nice to hear :) You should keep in mind when working with Mapbox that mapbox.js actually is an extended version of Leaflet. In my experience when looking for general answers you're better off with the Leaflet reference guide than the mapbox api docs unless it's specific to a mapbox extension of Leaflet.

Comment: Great thanks for the tip... The only problem I am having with my map now is that I get a parseerror when loading the geoJSON via ajax as I was doing with the previous data!

Comment: I see i've left (remnant from the example i c/p it from) a semicolon at the end of the array. Edited my code. Otherwise that's perfectly valid JSON, just c/p and validate it with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), you'll see. That should give no problems with fetching that through ajax. What's wrong with your ajax is kind of hard to tell without an example or some code but that's kind of beyond the scope of the current question. Maybe better to start a new one.

Comment: Ahhh thanks for the JSONLint link! Was hoping to find a tool like this - Pretty new to JSON and I made the mistake of placing '//' styled comments throughout it which caused the parseerror!

Comment: Again, no problem and good to hear it's solved. Indeed as you discovered comments aren't a part of the JSON specification and thus will cause parsing errors. :)